# Wrapping text horizontally and use overflow:hidden vertically

Tags: html, css

My problem is simple: I have a `div` that is limited via `relative` constraints. Inside this div I have a bullet point list via `ul`. On extremely small viewports the list text will be larger than the containing `div`.

I am using `overflow: hidden;` but that clips my text both vertically and horizontally. Instead my goal is to wrap my lines horizontally and only clip vertically.

Is this possible without using Javascript?

Comment: _“I have a `div` that is limited via `relative` constraints”_ – what are _“`relative` constraints”_ supposed to be? Can only assume that you are talking about relative positioning here ... but totally unclear then what that would “restrain” ...?

Comment: Relativ positioning is a CSS specific term describing a very specific kind of positioning. `Contraints` are a more generic way of expressing the situation. There are other possible CSS/HTML constellation that will lead to a layout with relative constraints, without using `position:relative;`.

Comment: You don’t have to explain to me what relative positioning is ... But in combination with “constraints” that just makes little sense to me. A constraint is a technical limitation or sth. like that. Relative positioning doesn’t “constrain” anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `overflow` attribute has 2 "siblings": `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` just for what you need...

So just use `overflow-y: hidden;`...

See: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can use this...

```
overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;
```